# absent from work vs. absent from some meetings

Tags: word-choice

Hi!
I read the following from a TOEIC book:
 
MEMO
To: All staff
From: Donna Rutherford, Personnel Director
Date: 2 May
Subject: Guyana Financial Services
Communication Guidelines
1. Attendance at departmental and all-staff
meetings is expected. You must obtain prior approval from your manager to be
excused.
2. Whenever you are out of the office for
one or more days, please indicate the dates of your absence on your online
calendar.
3. …
Thank you for your attention to these
company guidelines.
 
GUYANA FINANCIAL SERVICES (GFS)
May Calendar of Indira Sharma
…
15(Mon) – Loan inquiry: Mr. and Ms. Hill
16(Tue) – Retail banking department meeting
17(Wed) – Work on Hill family mortgage
contract
18(Thu) – Travel to CABE Conference in
Suriname
19(Fri) – CABE Conference
…
 
Q. For what date would Ms. Sharma need her
manager’s approval to be **absent from work**?
(A) May 15
(B) May 16
(C) May 17
(D) May 18
 
(Answer: B)
 
I think the above question has an error in
it.
I think “absent from work” should be corrected
into “absent from some meetings”, because in #1 of the memo
the director says all staff should obtain approval from their manager to be
excused from ‘attending the meetings’, NOT from ‘going to work’.
 
What do you think? Do you agree with me?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The question doesn't want you to key in on specific phrases. It wants you to put together information from different places.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean what is the clear answer for the test - then B is the clear answer. It says you need approval to be absent from meetings.  There is a meeting on Tuesday, and being absent from work implies being absent from meetings.

If you mean in real life, then the answer is every day, unless by reasons out of the control of the employee (eg illness). And in real life there might be procedures for online attendance at meetings etc etc etc.  All this is beyond the scope of the question.

Comment: Now I understand why there's no error in the original question. I assumed "absent from work" ALWAYS means 'not going to work'. However, with the help of your explanation, now I've realized that "absent from work" SOMETIMES means "not doing work". In the above case, as you explained, "absent from work" means "absent from meetings".

Comment: Thank you for your clear explanation!